# Different performance of Dataflow jobs in different zones

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

We are working on an opensource [project](https://github.com/google/privacy-sandbox-aggregation-service) that runs Dataflow jobs with Apache Beam Go SDK.

We recently notice that jobs running on different worker locations (zones) have very different performances, e.g.

us-central1-a vs us-central1-f:

Wall time -- 1hr 21min vs 1hr 58min

Total vCPU -- 1129.907 vs 1727.49 vCPU hr

(Please see the pictures attached)

These jobs read exactly the same input in a GCS bucket (multi-region) and process it with the same code. But zone 'us-central1-a' consistently has better performance than 'us-central1-f'. Does anyone know what's the difference between them? Is there any instruction for how to select the zones?

Thanks in advance!

**us-central1-a:**
[image: us-central1-a]

**us-central1-f:**
[image: us-central1-f]

Answer (score -1):

To override the zone, see: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints#workeroverride.

About performance of different zones, the specs for each zone can be found in GCE's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#available). My guess is that the 2 zones probably have different default CPU platforms.

> For example, if you create an instance in the us-central1-a zone, your instance by default uses a Haswell processor, unless you specify another option.

You may want to double check if the 2 jobs have identical metrics and characteristics, i.e., the slowdown of us-central1-f is consistent and not caused by any hiccups of the job or its dependent systems. Additionally, you may check with an GCE expert to see if a different zone does provide different performance. And since the zone is auto-selected, it might be that the region/zone of us-central1-a was too busy at that time and you might have similar or worse performance at us-central1-a if it was executed there.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! We actually ran the same job in both specified zones for multiple times and the results were quite consistent, so it's less likely to be caused by hiccups.  I think your point on the CPU platforms makes sense, do you know how we can reach out to an GCE expert? And is there a method for the users to check how busy a zone is?

Comment: I don't think the underlying status of each region/zone is visible to end users. You may add "google-compute-engine" tags to your question and see if anyone can answer the performance difference question.

Comment: Got it, thanks allot!